# convergence of power series having polynomial as its coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Consider the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p(n)a_nz^n$. 
Let the degree of $p(x)=d$.
Given that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=R> 0$,
 find the radius of convergence of given power series.

My view :take $p(x)=a_1x^d+a_2x^{d-1}+\cdots+a_{d+1}$
Multiplying $p(n)$ and $a_n$, I get coefficients of power series. I apply ratio test using given limit. Since power add on multiplication, it should turn out that radius is $R+d or Rd$. 
Is this approach OK? 
Am I justified in taking $p(x)$ to be an expression like the way I have defined? 
Any other methods would be equally appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly valid to take $p(x) = b_1x^d + b_2x^{d-1} + \cdots + b_{d+1}$ (although it is more common to write $p(x) = b_0 + b_1 x + \cdots + b_{d}x^d$.  Also note that I have used $b$'s instead of $a$'s to avoid confusion between the polynomial coefficients and the terms $a_n$).

Then, applying the ratio test, we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{p(n+1) a_{n+1}z^{n+1}}{p(n)a_nz^n} = z\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{p(n+1)}{p(n)} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}.$$
The last limit we know is $R$ from the information given. It is also true that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{p(n+1)}{p(n)} = 1$$
as you can verify by substituting in your expression for $p(x)$ and dividing the top and bottom by $n^d$.

Now, can you solve for the radius of convergence from here?

Comment: Seems something wrong. This way I get 1/R as radius of convergence.

Comment: No, that's correct.  The radius is still $1/R$.  Since polynomials grow slower than any exponential, it makes sense that multiplying every term in a power series by a polynomial in $n$ does not change the radius of convergence, which is governed by the exponential term $z^n$.  This is what you've shown.